# How to find nearest neighbors in SMOTE

Tags: dataset, class-imbalance, smote

I am reading the original paper by Chawla and others for SMOTE. I am trying to understand how to generate these synthetic examples for over-sampling the minority class. The paper says:

"Synthetic samples are generated in the following way: Take the difference between the feature vector (sample) under consideration and its nearest neighbor. Multiply this difference by a random number between 0 and 1, and add it to the feature vector under consideration. This causes the selection of a random point along the line segment between two specific features".

I understand the idea, take your sample, the nearest neighbor, pick a random point in between, what I don't understand is how these nearest neighbors are defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compute the Euclidean distance between each point and sort theses distances.

That said, you can find an implementation in the [imbalanced-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn) toolbox. More precisely, you can see the different steps of the implementation that you mentioned: (i) [fit a KNN](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/master/imblearn/over_sampling/smote.py#L303), (ii) [find the NN of each sample](http://s://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/master/imblearn/over_sampling/smote.py#L307), (iii) [generate a new samples](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/master/imblearn/over_sampling/smote.py#L231).

Answer (score 0):

The nearest neighbor will be the sample with the smaller Euclidean distance.